# Создание интерактивной карты leaflet-ajax

Tags: javascript, карты, geojson

Для создания интерактивной карты, состоящей из нескольких слоёв, использую плагин leaflet-ajax с загрузкой файлов .geojson. При наведении на объект слоя выводится атрибутивная информация (атрибуты объекта).

Требуется, чтобы в числе атрибутов объекта была ссылка на html page.

Как это сделать?

Код представлен ниже

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

    "features": [
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Внешний вид", "id": 2, "Дата установки": "2012\/02\/05", "материал": "пластик", "Кол-во_динамиков": 1, "опора,фидер": "2 2" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 34.377387101428354, 54.063054027736584 ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 4, "Дата установки": "2012\/02\/05", "материал": "пластик", "Кол-во_динамиков": 1, "опора,фидер": "4 2" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 34.378052287959541, 54.062481025595972 ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 6, "Дата установки": "2012\/02\/05", "материал": "пластик", "Кол-во_динамиков": 2, "опора,фидер": "6 2" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 34.379007152496243, 54.062134701791955 ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 8, "Дата установки": "2012\/02\/05", "материал": "пластик", "Кол-во_динамиков": 2, "опора,фидер": "8 2" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 34.379050067756317, 54.061882828120638 ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 10, "Дата установки": "2012\/02\/05", "материал": "пластик", "Кол-во_динамиков": 2, "опора,фидер": "10 2" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 34.379908372957857, 54.061209058541877 ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 12, "Дата установки": "2012\/02\/05", "материал": "пластик", "Кол-во_динамиков": 2, "опора,фидер": "12 2" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 34.380487728968895, 54.060774565820481 ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 14, "Дата установки": "2012\/02\/05", "материал": "пластик", "Кол-во динамиков": 2, "опора,фидер": "14 2" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 34.381142186685068, 54.060497495624809 ] ] } }
    ]
}
```

Кода страницы

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Leaflet - выводим слой OpenStreetMap</title>

 <!-- Добавляем файлы стилей CSS для библиотеки -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Control.Measure.css" />
 <!--[if lte IE 8]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5/leaflet.ie.css" />
 <![endif]-->

  <!-- Добавляем ссылку на JS-скрипт библиотеки -->
 <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
 <script src="./leaflet-ajax-gh-pages/dist/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>
 <script src="Control.Measure.js"></script>

 <style>

#map {width: 1300px; height: 600px; }

 </style>



</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>

//Определяем карту, координаты центра и начальный масштаб
map = L.map('map').setView([54.064751, 34.374456], 12);

//Добавляем на нашу карту слой OpenStreetMap
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

//function popUp(feature, layer) {

//    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name)
var dorogi = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("shkaf.geojson",{onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {     
        layer.bindPopup(Object.keys(feature.properties).join("<br />"),{maxHeight:200});
        layer.setStyle({ color: '#0000FF', clickable: true, weight: 4, opacity: 0.8});
      }
    });

var lines = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("lines.geojson", {onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {     
        layer.bindPopup(Object.keys(feature.properties).join("<br />"),{maxHeight:200});
        layer.setStyle({ color: '#0000FF', clickable: true, weight: 4, opacity: 0.8});
      }
    });

var DPS = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("DPS2.geojson", {onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties) {
        var info = function(k){
            var str = k + ": " + feature.properties[k];
        return str;
    }     
        layer.bindPopup(Object.keys(feature.properties).map(info).join("<br />"),{maxHeight:200});
        layer.setStyle({ color: '#00FF87', clickable: true, weight: 4, opacity: 0.8});
      }
    }});

var lines_DPS = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("lines1_DPS.geojson", {onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {     
        layer.bindPopup(Object.keys(feature.properties).join("<br />"),{maxHeight:200});
        layer.setStyle({ color: '#0000FF', clickable: true, weight: 4, opacity: 0.8});
      }
    });

var lines_kabel = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("lines_kabel.geojson", {onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {     
        layer.bindPopup(Object.keys(feature.properties).join("<br />"),{maxHeight:200});
        layer.setStyle({ color: '#0000FF', clickable: true, weight: 4, opacity: 0.8});
      }
    });


var kabel = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("kabel_canalisation.geojson", {onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {     
        layer.bindPopup(Object.keys(feature.properties).join("<br />"),{maxHeight:200});
        layer.setStyle({ color: '#0000FF', clickable: true, weight: 4, opacity: 0.8});
      }
    });


var baseMaps = {};
    var overlayMaps = {
      "Шкаф местной связи": dorogi,
      "Кабели местной связи": lines,
      "Опоры ДПС": DPS,
      "фидерные линии ДПС": lines_DPS,
      "кабельные колодцы": kabel,
      "кабельная канализация": lines_kabel,
    };

    L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
    L.control.measure().addTo(map);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: код весь с html сюда